# How to hide all pages before login

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, web-applications, streamlit

Issues regarding multipage authentication. I created an application using python streamlit's library, total 4 pages (Login, Home, others, About) are there and Login page is the default page. Now the problem is without login or Sign Up I can access all other pages (Home, others, About). So, there is no point in making a login page separately.

I am trying to make a streamlit application such that when the application is visited, only one page is shown in the sidebar, “Sign In” page. When successfully sign-in, the application should show the other pages in the sidebar and hide the **Sign In** page and log out button create in the sidebar with this button user can again go back to the **log in** page. Means If log in page is activate then all other pages will be hide .

To do this, I would need to hide/show pages in the sidebar based on certain conditions (in my case, based on whether the user has successfully **logged in** then will be show all pages). However, it looks like whatever is in the pages folder WILL be rendered as a page on the sidebar by default, and there’s no way to customise which pages get rendered when.

**Here is the Code of Log In Page**

```
# Setup
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import hashlib

# Convert Pass into hash format
def make_hashes(password):
    return hashlib.sha256(str.encode(password)).hexdigest()

# Check password matches during login
def check_hashes(password,hashed_text):
    if make_hashes(password) == hashed_text:
        return hashed_text
    return False

# DB Management
import sqlite3 
conn = sqlite3.connect('user_data.db')
c = conn.cursor()
# DB Functions for create table
def create_usertable():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userstable(username TEXT,email TEX, password TEXT)')

# Insert the data into table
def add_userdata(username,email,password):
    c.execute('INSERT INTO userstable(username,email,password) VALUES (?,?,?)',(username,email,password))
    conn.commit()

# Password and email fetch
def login_user(email,password):
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM userstable WHERE email =? AND password = ?',(email,password))
    data = c.fetchall()
    return data


def view_all_users():
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM userstable')
    data = c.fetchall()
    return data


# Mian function
def main():
    #"""Login page"""
    st.title("welcome! ")
    menu = ["Login","SignUp"]
    choice = st.selectbox("Select Login or SignUp from dropdown box ▾",menu,)
    st.markdown(
     "<h10 style='text-align: left; color: #ffffff;'> If you do not have an account, create an accouunt by select SignUp option from above dropdown box.</h10>",
     unsafe_allow_html=True
     )
    if choice == "":
        st.subheader("Login")
    elif choice == 'Login':
        st.write('-------')
        st.subheader('Log in to the App')

        email = st.text_input("User Name",placeholder='email')
        
        password = st.text_input("Password",type='password')
  
        if st.checkbox("Login"):
            # if password == '12345':
            # Hash password creation and store in a table
            create_usertable()
            hashed_pswd = make_hashes(password)

            result = login_user(email,check_hashes(password,hashed_pswd))
            if result:

                st.success("Logged In as {}".format(email))

                
                if st.success:
                    st.subheader("User Profiles")
                    user_result = view_all_users()
                    clean_db = pd.DataFrame(user_result,columns=["Username","Email","Password"])
                    st.dataframe(clean_db)
            else:
                st.warning("Incorrect Username/Password")
    elif choice == "SignUp":
        st.write('-----')
        st.subheader("Create New Account")
        new_user = st.text_input("Username",placeholder='name')
        new_user_email = st.text_input('Email id',placeholder='email')
        new_password = st.text_input("Password",type='password')

        if st.button("Signup"):
            if new_user == '':     # if user name empty then show the warnings
                st.warning('Inavlid user name')
            elif new_user_email == '':   # if email empty then show the warnings
                st.warning('Invalid email id')
            elif new_password == '':   # if password empty then show the warnings
                st.warning('Invalid password')
            else:
                create_usertable()
                add_userdata(new_user,new_user_email,make_hashes(new_password))
                st.success("You have successfully created a valid Account")
                st.info("Go up and Login to you account")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Here is the image of application ⬆️

Is there a way to achieve conditional rendering of pages on the sidebar, using Streamlit’s?

Comment: This is one reason I do not use the pages feature. This is not possible some months back. I don't know if this issue has been addressed by the dev.

Answer (score 0):

you can use st.session_state to set sidebar 'collapsed' or 'expanded'
code like this:

```
# set sidebar collapsed before login
if 'sidebar_state' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.sidebar_state = 'collapsed'

# hide collapsed control button
hide_bar = """
           <style>
           [data-testid='collapsedControl"] {visibility:hidden;}
           </style>
           """

# set sidebar expanded after login
if login_after:
    st.session_state.sidebar_state = 'expanded'
else:
    st.session_state.sidebar_state = 'collapsed'
    st.markdown(hide_bar, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the pervious answeryou need to set the initial page config for it to work like this:

```py
if 'sidebar_state' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.sidebar_state = 'collapsed'
st.set_page_config(initial_sidebar_state=st.session_state.sidebar_state)
```